# What could be the reason for chain skipping

Tags: chain, freewheel, skipping

My chain is skipping only on the smallest sprocket, and it skips with every crank turn. The chain is not stretched. Also, chainrings are almost new. Could this freewheel be the reason, it doesn't seem worn out to me (although it's old):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Another pic showing the derailleur might help. Doubt its the freewheel.

Comment: I would check the limit screw, maybe turn it half a turn anti clockwise.

Comment: @KenHiatt: I added another pic.

Comment: @alex: Good idea, I'll try that.

Comment: Was thinking it might have been the upper pulley making contact, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Those rear sprockets appear to be in good condition.  The derailer or hanger may be bent, or the derailer limit or the shifter may be preventing the derailer from swinging all the way to the outside.  Or the chain may be too long.

Comment: The same problem existed with the previous derailer, which I replaced because its topmost spring was broken and it couldn't properly tighten the chain, I thought that was the cause of skipping. So I doubt it's the derailer problem. Also, I did notice that the chain is a bit slack. And this derailer doesn't have B-screw that I could tighten it a bit.

Comment: Check your chain for stiff links.  Watch it as it bends through the derailleur for any hops or links that don't pivot smoothly.  This could be causing shifting issues.

Comment: No stiff links. Also, the chain length is OK. It seems that the problem is in the derailer high limit. I will be able to confirm during the weekend. :)

Comment: No luck yet. Still skips on the smallest sprocket, even after playing with the limit screw. Next stop: replacing the freewheel (I have a spare one).

Comment: As you slowly pedal, does the chain try to jump up to the next sprocket, or is it jumping off to the outside of the bike?

Comment: For me it looks like the small cogs has slightly bent teeth. Also, how you measured your chain stretch? The bike is not looks new and chain has no oil on it. It can be a situation you using small front chainring and small cog and they just wear out faster then other cogs? If chain stretched out it skips on your preferred cog first and works fine on others.

Answer (score 2):

The reason was the sprocket after all. Changing the freewheel resolved the issue. I had some problem finding a service which has the wrench for that old Sachs/Maillard freewheels. Replaced it with standard Shimano 6-speed, and everything works smoothly now!

Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 1):

Sprocket, cassette and chain match together.  An old set will work well but change one part and you'll be skipping.  Often people will wear out their favorite gears, change the chain and then only the less favorite gears work reliably.

The problem is that the chain will actually ride up high on the teeth, eventually so high that they're not all in position and the chain-reaction of skip occurs; the sprocket teeth graze the chain links uncontrollably in that ever-so-painful sound.

The derailleur is surely not the problem (as you noticed).  If it were you would first here the clack-clack-clack from the out of alignment.

Comment: Actually, this is something of an old wive's tail.  As a sprocket wears the "ideal" link spacing actually gets smaller.  Too often people fail to replace a worn chain because they believe this, and it can cause worn but still good sprockets to become worn out fairly quickly.